# Determining the best way to compute a double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The question is:
[image]

When graphed, this is what it looks like:

[image]

I thought that the best way to do it would be with respect to y first, then x.

The bounds:

x/sqrt3 < y < sqrt(4-x^2)

1 < x < sqrt3

But upon trying to calculate, this seems very complicated.

SHould I try polar coordinates or something?

Comment: Change to polar coordinates

Comment: In particular, compute the angles of your lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have $x^2 + y^2$, I suggest using polar coordinates.

Since $$r^2 = x^2 + y^2$$

$$1 < r^2 < 4$$

So,

$$1 < r < 2$$

To find $\theta$

$$\pi/6 < \theta < \pi/3$$

Don't forget to multiply $$rdrd\theta\ \text{in your double integral}$$

Comment: Why do I need to multipy r in?

Comment: Its your "jacobian" value. Please visit this site if you want to know what that is. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As it's a little complicated with finding the indefinite integral of $$\int\int(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}dydx$$ I would suggest using polar, as reversing the order of integration isn't really going to make a huge difference. Also the graph is a huge indicator of that.